# How to configure Spring Cloud Eureka in Standalone HTTPS

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have used Eureka several times previously in HTTP (non-SSL).
However, I am trying to configure the Eureka Server in Standalone mode.
Unfortunately, the Server can't seem to register itself.

The Client applications are able to register without a problem.

The Server attempts to connect to http instead of https

(Using org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-parent:Dalston.SR1)

Here is my Eureka Server config:

```
server:
  port: 8761
  transport: https
  name: localhost

eureka:
  instance:
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    securePort: ${server.port}
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${eureka.instance.securePort}/eureka/
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
The main issue was that my application.yml is located in the wrong directory.

The directory was names **resource** instead of **resources**.

After renaming the directory, my problem seems to be solved.